# jQuery select by custom attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to select a div which has a custom attribute like the one below?

```
<div score="Result:78c61ce9">
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)?

Comment: It is not my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to select the div with certain score you could use this. That will get each div with that value of a score.
`$('div[score="Result:78c61ce9"]')`

And if you wanted to find it based on a certain result which was in a variable you could do

`$('div[score="Result:' + val + '"]')`

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
$('td[score=value]')
```